# Could not find class when launch ".bat" file

Tags: java, unit-testing

I launch a ".bat" file to launch one java test 
the file contains :

```
<path to java> -cp<all jar available in the classpath> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore 
<Package.classname>
```

all jar are separated by ";"
when I launch the ".bat"file ,I see the following message on the cmd window : 
JUnit version 4.6
Could not find class: tester.Test

Time: 0

OK (0 tests)

Comment: you should really really really look at using ANT to drive Java related things like this. It is cross platform and heavily documented and has a lot of stuff for doing things like this "batteries included"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is tester.Test.class in the class path?  That may be as simple as adding "." to the classpath.

Comment: I have : -cp ././mwt.jar;.... org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Tester.test
a space between the last jar and the "org.junit.runner.JUnitCore" and a space between "org.junit.runner.JUnitCore"  and the classename

Comment: Did you try putting the "." in the classpath?

Comment: you mean by this : .classpath? if it is the case it doesn't work it is not recognized

Comment: No, I mean "-cp .;foo.jar;bar.jar;[other jars]"